# How to automatically connect a new user to an existing node in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-dynamic-links

I've been trying to build a chore management app with React Native.
I've got basic CRUD functionality and user authentication with Firebase down so now I want to move on to user management.
Right now, there's only one user which is connected to one chore list, but I also want users to **invite other users to their chore list and create and delete chores together.**

I'm planning my database like below.

```js
- chore-lists
  - chorer-list 1
  - chorer-list 2
  - chorer-list 3
  - chorer-list 4
- users
  - user 1
    - chorer-list 1
  - user 2
    - chorer-list 2
  - user 3
    - chorer-list 3
  - user 4
    - chorer-list 4
```

Below is my user story:

User 1, Koki, wants to invite her partner, Jun, to use her chore-list together, but Jun doesn't have a user account.

1. I want Koki to send an invitation email from the app
2. Jun receives the email and clicks a link getting navigated to App Store
3. Jun signs in her Google account to the app and gets to use Koki's chore-list together

Questions:

To make the story happen, the Jun's new user ID needs to be automatically associated with chore-list 1.

**Is there any way you can connect a new user ID to an existing node when the user first time signs in?**

I'm thinking about using Firebase Dynamic Links for invitation email. Is it possible to add the chore-list key as payload in url parameters and connect the new user ID with the key.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to add the chore-list key as a URL parameter in the deep-link you set in your Firebase Dynamic Link, and use that to share and open that chore-list in the app the first time a new user installs or opens the app.

You can do that via something like the following if you're creating a short-link URL:

```
 // Create Firebase Dynamic Link and prepare share intent with FDL data.
 final Task<ShortDynamicLink> shortLinkTask = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
         .createDynamicLink()
         .setLink(Uri.parse("https://example.com/chores?choreList=" + choreListId))
         .setDomainUriPrefix("https://mychores.page.link")
         .setAndroidParameters(new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder().build())
         .buildShortDynamicLink(ShortDynamicLink.Suffix.SHORT);
```

After generating the short-link, you'll want to add an onCompleteListener that can present the sharing UI to send the link to another user. For more details and options on that part, check out the [user-to-user sharing guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/use-cases/user-to-user).

For connecting the newly signed in user to the chore list, the easiest way would probably be to generate a temporary invitation id and store that a user with that invitation id can access a given chore list. You can then pass that invitation id along in the sharing URL as well as throughout the login or sign-in flow. After the user logs in, you can perform a check to see if the invitation id for the chore-list id matches before deciding to show that chore list to that user.

This is a basic approach though and isn't very secure, but it's a start. Depending on how secure you want to keep the chore list data, you might need to add additional checks here.